# extract value from an invalid/part xml using regex in java

Tags: java, xml, regex

I have an xml like this which is obtained direcly from databse(which need not be a valid one with proper opening and ending tags).I need to etraxct data from this xml eg. color,level,prefix etc. Since proper xml format is not guaranteed the only way for me to do it is Regex..or is it??

The xml looks something like this

```
<indicator label_unit_en="Index points" label_unit_de="Basis punkte">  
<partition id="P_ABC_DEF.3">    
<part color="darkgreen"   level="50"    prefix_en="aaa 111"   prefix_de="unt ü 50">    
<part color="lightgreen"  level="100"   prefix_en="50 to 100"  prefix_de="qwe 100">    
<part color="lightorange" level="200"   prefix_en="100 to 200" prefix_de="100 qw 200">    
<part color="darkorange"  level="300"   prefix_en="200 to 300" prefix_de="20 w0">    
<part color="lightred"    level="500"   prefix_en="300 to 500" prefix_de="rr 0">    
part color="darkred"     level="99999" prefix_en="above 500"  prefix_de="ü 2">  
</partition>
</indicator>
```

Can any one suggest me a way to extract data from this xml???

I am able to extract data from 
`color(color=\"(\\w+?)\"), 
level(level=\"(\\w+?)\)`, 
but not from the others.

Any of the matcher that I created is not finding anything for `prefix_en,prefix_de, label_unit_en, label_unit_de`

Please suggest a solution for this. Or is there any way other than regex to solve this problem.

Comment: 'Since proper xml format is not guaranteed' Why that?

Comment: the so called 'xml' hich i am getting need not be a valid one you can see in the example that its not having proper closing tags

Comment: I see that. But *why* is this the case? How is such broken XML generated in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, initial XML can be converted to well-formed with libraries like http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/, and then extract data with xPath or node scanning.

Answer (score 0):

The code you had pasted needs much formatting to be treated as xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<indicator label_unit_en="Index points" label_unit_de="Basis punkte">  
<partition id="P_ABC_DEF.3">    
<part color="darkgreen"   level="50"    prefix_en="aaa 111"   prefix_de="unt ü 50"/>    
<part color="lightgreen"  level="100"   prefix_en="50 to 100"  prefix_de="qwe 100"/>    
<part color="lightorange" level="200"   prefix_en="100 to 200" prefix_de="100 qw 200"/>    
<part color="darkorange"  level="300"   prefix_en="200 to 300" prefix_de="20 w0"/>    
<part color="lightred"    level="500"   prefix_en="300 to 500" prefix_de="rr 0"/>    
<part color="darkred"     level="99999" prefix_en="above 500"  prefix_de="ü 2"/>  
</partition>
</indicator>
```

If you format it to xml as sugested by pasha701, you can get the values, else you can do string operations on this as :

```
    String result = "<indicator label_unit_en=\"Index points\" label_unit_de=\"Basis punkte\">"+  
              "<partition id=\"P_ABC_DEF.3\">"+    
              "<part color=\"darkgreen\"   level=\"50\"    prefix_en=\"aaa 111\"   prefix_de=\"unt ü 50\">"+    
              "<part color=\"lightgreen\"  level=\"100\"   prefix_en=\"50 to 100\"  prefix_de=\"qwe 100\">"+    
              "<part color=\"lightorange\" level=\"200\"   prefix_en=\"100 to 200\" prefix_de=\"100 qw 200\">"+           
              "</partition>"+
              "</indicator>";

System.out.println(x.substring(x.indexOf("color=")+7,x.indexOf(" ", x.indexOf("color="))-1));
```

Tell us what would you like, and would help accordingly.